# Angular - Dynamic ng-model inside ng-repeater

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a form for search data, some fields are generated dinamically inside a ng-repeat. The problem is to assign ng-model to all fields that i must get to do the search.

I need to use the {{masterAttribute.Name}} as ng-model, or whatever that i can read to do in my search.

HTML is

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="ricercaAttivita">
    <div class="accordion-group" ng-repeat="masterAttribute in masterAttributes">
        <select class="trip dark" ng-model="{{masterAttribute.Name}}" ng-options="attr.Id as attr.Value for attr in masterAttribute.Values">
            <option value="">TUTTE</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-green btn-3-column sidebar-filtri-button" ng-click="search()">Cerca</button>
</body>
```

Comment: it´s posible using `ng-model="masterAttribute.Name"`

Comment: if`search()`  method is part of your controller , then you also have access to `masterAttributes` as well in controller., you can find all `Name` props there.

Comment: ok but doing this i have this error: Error: [$parse:syntax]

Comment: another question: in my controller how i can get values? I mean, i can iterate masterAttributes but how can i read selected values? I can't do $scope.masterAttributes.Id, it returns "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Change `ng-model="{{masterAttribute.Name}}"` to `ng-model="masterAttribute.Name"`.

since it's already in Angular scope, so no need of interpolation operator(**{{..}}**).

Further : `search()` method is part of your `ricercaAttivita` controller, then you also have access to `masterAttributes` as well in controller., you can find all `Name` props there.

Comment: Thanks, now it's ok!

Comment: But i have another problem now, i have a link (i need it for accordion menu) like this: <a>{{masterAttribute.Name}}</a>, when i select something in my select with ng-model masterAttribute.Name also the link change. How can i do to not chanche the link?

Comment: You can either change your ng-model value to something else or capture the correponding masterAttribute.Name value in a new variable in your controller and put that variable there in the link.

Comment: @user8060797: as Vivz said, when `accordion` is bind to same prop `ng-model` of `select`, then it will change, you have to create `new $scope prop` in controller and bind that prop to accordion., So if it helps mark as answer.