# Angular - Get ng-model value generated dinamically

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

My problem is directly connected with this

[Angular - Dynamic ng-model inside ng-repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44430277/angular-dynamic-ng-model-inside-ng-repeater)

All works fine, it means that all selects are gereratet correctly with all options. The problem is in the controller, i can't get the ng-models'value, it returns "undefined" and i don't know how i can to this.

This is my HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="ricercaAttivita">
    <div class="accordion-group" ng-repeat="masterAttribute in masterAttributes">
        <select class="trip dark" ng-model="{{masterAttribute.Name}}" ng-options="attr.Id as attr.Value for attr in masterAttribute.Values">
            <option value="">TUTTE</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-green btn-3-column sidebar-filtri-button" ng-click="search()">Cerca</button>
</body>
```

CONTROLLER

```
var tantoSvagoApp = angular.module('MyApp'); 

tantoSvagoApp.controller("ricercaAttivita") {
  $scope.search = function(page) {
    angular.forEach($scope.masterAttributes,function(value,index){
       console.log($scope.masterAttributes.Name);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove **{{..}}** from `ng-model`.
Change it to : `ng-model="masterAttribute.Name"`

and, in controller use the iterator (*value*) not `$scope` prop inside foreach,

Do it Like :

```
var tantoSvagoApp = angular.module('MyApp'); 

tantoSvagoApp.controller("ricercaAttivita") {
  $scope.search = function(page) {
    angular.forEach($scope.masterAttributes,function(masterAttribute,index){
       console.log(masterAttribute.Name);
    }
  }
}
```

Told you same in [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44430277/angular-dynamic-ng-model-inside-ng-repeater) as well :)

Comment: I'm sorry, i paste the incorrect code. I did what you say, i removed {{...}} and i just use the the iterator, but unfortunately i get always "undefined"

Comment: @user8060797:  do you have values in `masterAttributes`, ? before iterating. or could you create fiddle\plunker

Comment: ok, my mistake, now it works, but how i can get selected value? If i do console.log(value.Name) i have the ng-model of select, but how i can get the selected option?

Comment: @user8060797 :  `ng-model` is the selected option,. both are same.

Comment: @user8060797 : could you also [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and upvote both the answers (this and previous qstn).. so there is no unanswered qstn and other get help as well